# How to get to Home Screen in Expo on Android

Tags: react-native, expo

Dumb little question.

In the iOS simulator I can hit cmd+D to get to the menu and there's a button for "Go to Expo Home".

In Android emulator I can hit cmd+M to get a similar menu, but it doesn't have an option to go to the home screen.

How do I get to the Expo Home? I am **not** talking about my app's splash screen.

Comment: open terminal and `adb shell input keyevent 82`

Comment: Not the device's home screen.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to expo, but I've noticed that if you hit the Android square button and choose expo it keeps your app loaded, BUT if you hit the android circle button and then choose Expo from the app list/home screen it opens expo to the expo home screen.  Not as seamless as iOS, but it works.